# Boostrap-select is not loading options in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap select 1.7.5 with bootstrap 3.4.0 but there is some issue bootstrap-select not loading the options

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="store-type"name="select-identification-number">
   <option>EIN</option>
   <option>SSN / ESN</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include both the CSS, JS files in your index.html?

If you inspect element, you will see that the class `selectpicker` has the property `display: none!important;` which is why you don't see it... just remove this class and you'll see it

relevant **HTML**:

```
<select class="" id="store-type" name="select-identification-number">
   <option>EIN</option>
   <option>SSN / ESN</option>
</select>
```

example [on stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crv9lt)

but having a package which requires JS file is not the best idea... you should go for an angular2+ compatible package which gives you this feature...